In Scala 3, what's the meaning of "unreducible application of higher-kinded type"?
Here is a short example:

object ErrorCase {

  type K[T] = T => Seq[T]

  type KI = K[? >: Nothing <: Int]
// not working
/*
unreducible application of higher-kinded type [T] =>> T => Seq[T] to wildcard arguments

Explanation
===========
An abstract type constructor cannot be applied to wildcard arguments.
Such applications are equivalent to existential types, which are not
supported in Scala 3.

*/

  type KI2 = (? >: Nothing <: Int) => Seq[? >: Nothing <: Int] // works despite equivalent
}


this explanation is not suitable enough, as K[T] is a very concrete type constructor that can be resolved immediately, not an abstract type constructor
What's the cause of this error? Is it a compiler bug?
UPDATE 1, Obviously the bound ? >: Nothing <: Int is quite useless in practice, but similar definition may be frequently encountered in refining polymorphic function to a normal function, e.g. the following definition:
type KI = K[? >: Tuple2[?,?] <: Product]

can be normalised to (using the variance/monotonicity of function definition (-I) => (+O)):
 = (? >: Tuple[?,?] <: Product) => Seq[? >: Tuple[?,?] <: Product]
 = Tuple[?,?] => Seq[Product]

which is very normal. It can even be inlined for both concrete & abstract K[T], but that's a different augmentation.

I am I NOT convinced that these 2 are equivalent. In Scala 2 both ? would be different existential types, I suspect the same is true about Scala 3.

I guess the real use case doesn't allow this, but what about just using K[Int] and maybe making K[+T] so it is covariant?

that kind of works for Int => Seq[T], but T as a function input is contravariant/decreasing on the type poset

@tribbloid Could you please give an example of how a value of type KI should be used? Given f: KI, for what type of x would f(x) type-check? And what do you want the type of f(x) to be?

@MattBovel good question, that's just a toy example to poke soundness, I'll add a more realistic example to the body of the question
